# Irreducible root system decomposition

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for the name of and a good reference on the following theorem

**Theorem**: let $G$ be a connected, compact and semisimple Lie group, and $T \subset G$ a maximal torus of $G$, there exists a unique collection of subtori $T_i$ in $T$ such that

1. $\prod{T_i} \to T$ is an isogeny therefore $\prod{\chi(T_i)_{\mathbb{Q}}} \hookleftarrow \chi(T)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is an isomorphism
2. $\{(\chi(T_i)_{\mathbb{Q}}\}$ are the irreducible components of $\chi(T)_{\mathbb{Q}}$

let $G_i = Z_G(\prod_{k\neq i}{T_k})'$, the collection $\{G_i\}$ satisfy

1. $\prod{G_i} \to G$ is an isogeny
2. $G_i$'s pairwise commute
3. $G_i$ are minimal nontrivial closed connected normal subgroups of $G$, moreover every closed connected normal subgroup of $G$ is generated by some of these $G_i$'s
4. $T_i = T \cap G_i$ and are maximal tori in $G_i$ and $\Phi(G_i,T_i)$ are the weights of $\chi(T_i)_{\mathbb{Q}}$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Cross-posted (and closed because it's copied from a Stanford grad class homework) at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239983/irreducible-root-system-decomposition

Comment: the MO cross-post is now deleted by the author. The reference was Exercise 5 in http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210CPage/homework/hmwk9.pdf

Comment: Please look up the Stanford academic calendar.  I am asking the question AFTER the due date of the homework!

Comment: OK. If Math Overflow does not allow any post related to homework no matter what the content is please state it somewhere as a policy!